# Squish : getting error phonelauncher[1830:21892] Loading iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient failed:

Tags: xcode, squish

For an app in iOS, I was trying to run in iPhone 4S simulator and I was running squish automation done by other team which got migrated to mine.

When I try to record a new script I am getting error :

```
phonelauncher[1830:21892] Loading iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient failed: directory '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient.framework' is not a valid bundle directory

Runner exited with value 137
```

Any idea why this issue is happening ?